# How to update data when it exists, and not create when it does not exist, Laravel 5

Tags: sql, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a problem in my database query.
I first imported two entries like this [image: THIS], and the data was inserted correctly.

> wholesaler_id | target | week | total_transaction | rebate |
>   total_voucher
>
> ```
> 11223344      | 100.000| 1.2017| 50.000          | 2,25    | 0 
> 11223344      | 100.000| 2.2017| 120.000         | 2,25    | 2700
> 11223344      | 100.000| 3.2017| 185.000         | 2,25    | 1462,5
> 11223344      | 100.000| 4.2017| 248.000         | 2,25    | 1417,5
> ```

But when I import again with additional rows [image], the result is as follows:

> wholesaler_id | target | week | total_transaction | rebate |
>   total_voucher
>
> ```
> 11223344      | 100.000| 1.2017| 50.000          | 2,25    | 0 
> 11223344      | 100.000| 2.2017| 120.000         | 2,25    | 2700
> 11223344      | 100.000| 3.2017| 185.000         | 2,25    | 1462,5
> 11223344      | 100.000| 4.2017| 248.000         | 2,25    | 1417,5
> 11223344      | 100.000| 1.2017| 63.100          | 2,25    | 0 
> 11223344      | 100.000| 2.2017| 142.700         | 2,25    | 2700
> 11223344      | 100.000| 3.2017| 205.000         | 2,25    | 1462,5
> 11223344      | 100.000| 4.2017| 279.400         | 2,25    | 1417,5
> ```

The result I want is as follows:

```
wholesaler_id | target | week | total_transaction | rebate | total_voucher

11223344      | 100.000| 1.2017| 63.100          | 2,25    | 0 
11223344      | 100.000| 2.2017| 155.800         | 2,25    | 2700
11223344      | 100.000| 3.2017| 240.800         | 2,25    | 1462,5
11223344      | 100.000| 4.2017| 332.200         | 2,25    | 1417,5
```

The rebate and total voucher column is not a problem, the main problem is in `total_transaction` . 
This is the code in my Controller function `importCsv`

```
    $voucher = Voucher::firstOrCreate(array(
     'wholesaler_id' => $wholesaler_id,
     'target' => $target,
     'week' => $week . '.' . date("Y"),
     'total_transaction' => $sum,
     'rebate' => $wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage,
     'total_voucher' => $total_voucher
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be done like this ..

```
$voucher = Voucher::firstOrCreate(['wholesaler_id'=>$wholesaler_id],
    [
        'target' => $target,
        'week' => $week . '.' . date("Y"),
        'total_transaction' => $sum,
        'rebate' => $wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage,
        'total_voucher' => $total_voucher
    ]
);
```